# Submit username and password javascript (not a form)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a popup which asks the user for login information, which means two input text fields for password and username.

Now as I will be verifying the information using ajax I didn't wrap the elements on a  because form always needs a php action, correct? or am I missing something?

So I'd like to know if there is a fancier way to check if the user pressed enter, in order to submit the login information, than checking each time a key is pressed, with keydown, if it's the enter key.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need a form to wrap your user inputs, and that form still has an action. However, you won't do a full page post. Instead, you'll send an AJAX post. jQuery makes this really easy.

```
$(function() { 
  $("#myForm").submit(function () {
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var url = $(this).attr("action");
    $.post(url, data);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 for this, because if the javascript is off, the form will still submit!

Comment: but what action should I set in the <form> tag? nothing?

Comment: The action should be whatever endpoint performs your login operation.

Comment: @out_sider — as per my answer, it should be the URL to a server side process that will process the form data, act accordingly on it, and return an appropriate HTTP response (which is probably to redirect the user back to where they came from, or display an error message if their credentials are wrong).

Answer (score 1):

> Now as I will be verifying the information using ajax I didn't wrap the elements on a because form always needs a php action, correct? or am I missing something?

A form requires an action, it doesn't have to point to a URL that is processed by PHP. There are much nicer languages available (this is subjective).

What you are missing, is a fallback for when the JavaScript isn't run for some reason (such as the file not being downloaded due to a network glitch, the client not supporting JS or having JS, etc). [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build).

> So I'd like to know if there is a fancier way to check if the user pressed enter, in order to submit the login information, than checking each time a key is pressed, with keydown, if it's the enter key.

If you build on things that work, then you'll have a form anyway, and can run your JS in the `submit` handler. Then you don't need to care if the form was submitted by a keypress or a button click.

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute to form

```
<form onSubmit="call your javascript; return false;"> ...
```

so when enter, or submit button is pressed your javascript will be called and then you can do what ever you want with your form values. Reutrn false will prevent classic form submit.

I hope this helps

Comment: The question states that there isn't a form.

Comment: @David - there has to be a form, otherwise the HTML is invalid.

Comment: @Charles — nothing in the DTDs require that input, button, textarea or select elements have a form element in their ancestry. The HTML is valid (even if it of low quality). I'm 99% sure that the non-machine processable parts of the spec don't require it either, so it is fully conforming to the (X)HTML recommendations.

Comment: and If I leave the action empty by doing <form action=""> is this wrong? I know I should assure functionality when JS isn't available but my site is build based on ajax so besides that is there a problem?